# Object Particle is not resting above the face of the specified object and also going out of bond. (Images Attached)

Tags: particles

[image: In the image I want the sprinkle particle to rest in the icing and also not to go in the donot]

The icing (pink part) is a child of the donut (brown part). Is that the problem for the particles going in the donut as well?

And also why is it hovering above the icing?

Comment: You can fix the "hovering" by selecting your sprinkle object (the one you instanced for the particles), and moving it around in edit mode - you'll see what it does. Find a place where the sprinkles seem to lay on the surface of the donut. If you only applied the particles to the icing, this might solve your second problem as well, as they should all be "in bounds" (on the icing, not the donut) after doing this.

Comment: That doesn't help

Comment: Does moving the particle object in edit mode change the location of the particles (inatances) relative to the donut? If not try unparenting (ALT+P) and see if that's the problem.

Comment: There was an issue with the object particle, therefore redoing it fixed it. Thank you for your help.